# appendChild with for loop and if i%3 ==0 I want to add a <br> after that number's input

Tags: javascript

```js
let buttonArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
for (let i of buttonArr) {
  let numberButton = document.createElement("input");
  numberButton.type = "button";
  numberButton.value = i;
  document.body.appendChild(numberButton);


  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    let breakMark = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild("breakMark");
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

I want to use `appendChild()` in JavaScript with for loop to add input tag to HTML base on the length of Array. I want only three button shows in one line, which is means after three new input tag been added to HTML I want to add a 
 element. My idea is if `i%3 == 0` then `appendChild()` `<br>` to HTML but it looks wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `document.body.appendChild("breakMark");` should be `document.body.append(breakMark)`

Comment: Code works perfectly fixing the `("breakMark")` -> `(breakMark)` typo, so I think the question is off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

> The `Node.appendChild()` method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, `appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).

By wrapping `breakMark` with quotes you are appending string literal not the value of the variable (which is a node). But since `Node.appendChild()` adds node not the DOMString, it throw the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

So remove the surrounding quotes so that the `appendChild()` takes the created node as the parameter:

```js
let buttonArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
for(let i of buttonArr){
  let numberButton = document.createElement("input");
  numberButton.type = "button";
  numberButton.value = i;
  document.body.appendChild(numberButton); 


  if(i%3 == 0){
      let breakMark = document.createElement("br");
      document.body.appendChild(breakMark); //remove the quotes
  }else{
      console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and I think I learned a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You had two issues, the first was that you were trying to call a function `appendChild`, <s>which didn't exist</s> which for some reason didn't work when I first fixed up the code, but appears to work now. I have no idea. the function is there, but it threw a big red error for me originally so I just assumed it didn't exist.

The second was that you were calling this function with the string literal `"breakMark"` instead of the variable `breakMark`

```js
let buttonArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
for (let i of buttonArr) {
  let numberButton = document.createElement("input");
  numberButton.type = "button";
  numberButton.value = i;
  document.body.appendChild(numberButton);


  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    let breakMark = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(breakMark);
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `appendChild`, I'm curious? Said method does indeed exist, and using it seems to work for me. `.append` is new-ish and not supported in IE, not sure why one would prefer it

Comment: From what I can tell `appendChild` expects a different parameter than `append` does (`Node` and `Element` respectively according to my Chrome Inspector)

Comment: Yep, though all `Element`s are `Node`s (and `<br>`s are both, so `appendChild` should work fine here, I'd think)

Answer (score 0):

I would create the html as a string from the array using a foEachloop and then insert it into the html in one hit. Rather than trying to append to the HTML on each iteration. This means that the DOM is manipulated only once rather than on each cycle.

```js
let buttonArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
var buttonStr = '';


buttonArr.forEach(function(button){
 buttonStr += '<input type = "button" value="'+ button +'"/>';
 button % 3 == 0 
  ? buttonStr += '<br/>'
  : console.log(button);
 })
 
 document.body.innerHTML = buttonStr;
```

Also - if you are using the buttons as buttons (eg on a calculator) it would be better to create them as buttons.

```js
    let buttonArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
    var buttonStr = '';


    buttonArr.forEach(function(button){
     buttonStr += '<button type = "button" value="'+ button +'" onclick="console.log(\'Value = \'+ this.value)">'+ button +'</button>';
     button % 3 == 0 
      ? buttonStr += '<br/>'
      : console.log(button);
     })
     
     document.body.innerHTML = buttonStr;
```